# SSIS Send Email File Attachment Failure

Tags: sql-server, validation, ssis, etl, sendmail

My SSIS Package creates a csv with the file name containing the date time stamp. I want to email this file. so i have a variable that contains wildcards to represent my file. I have set the send email task expression for file attachement to be my 2 variables

> @filelocation + @filename
>
> @filelocation = C:\User\project\
>
> @filename = final_ * _ *.csv

so it is looking for `C:\User\project\final_*_*.csv`

the file exists but I'm getting the following error

> Error at Send Mail Task [Send Mail Task]: Either the file "C:\User\project\final_*_*.csv" does not exist or you do not have permissions to access the file.
>
> Error at Send Mail Task: There were errors during task validation.

I have delayed validation but still doesn't work any suggestions would be appreciated. 
the file exists and I am running as administrator

Comment: C:\User\project\final_*_*.csv file is invalid file name format

Comment: * is wild card in file naming and does not allow by windows. use another charater like # or somthing else

Comment: why? the @filename variable uses * as a wildcard so it is looking for a filename "Final_WILDCARD_WILDCARD.csv. i have use this variable throughout the package and have no issues with using wildcard

Comment: The send mail task needs your expression to result in the exact path and file name of the attachment.

Comment: but because I wont know the exact name of file attachment as it includes time date stamp does this mean I cannot use wildcard variables for filename?

Comment: @sql2015 No, it doesn't.  You need to resolve the actual filename into a variable that sendmail can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to get files with the following pattern `final_ * _ *.csv`, add a `Foreach Loop Container` that retrieve files from `@filelocation` directory with the following pattern `final_ * _ *.csv` and for each file execute the Send Mail Task. *(If it is only one file, it will send only one)*

Or you have to Get the files using a Script Task and store the results in a variable then use it.